# How can I manage to set as blue a listview selected item as i see when clicked with mouse in Vb.Net?

Tags: listview, selected

This is the problem:

Using `ListView1.Items(0).Focused = True` I don't see any highlighting color.  Using `ListView1.Items(0).Focused = True` I see grey highlighting color. When I click with the mouse on one element I see highlighted blue. I would need to be highlighted blue as default when I show listview. How can I do that?

Comment: thanks to this stupid autocorrection algorithm i have here a very horrible output of my question

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `HideSelection` on the `ListView` to `false`. When `HideSelection` is `true` (which is the default), no row is highlighted when the list view isn't focused.

Also, you almost certainly want to set `Selected` rather than `Focused`. Selected rows are highlighted in blue -- the focused row is not.